# Create a ssh user in CentOS for FTP using WinSCP

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, centos-7

I want to create a new ssh user for file transfer and remote access using WinSCP. I am using CentOS 7. I have created a new user with a password. Also allowed the PasswordAuthentication in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf. But still I am unable to get the ssh session from this. What all configuration need to get the ssh session (via Username and Password). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? I'm assuming SSH works for other users, just not the new one? How did you make the new user (which command did you use)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, your newly created account must be a sudo account. To create one, you can create a new user normally.

Access your CentOS server:

```
ssh root@server_ip_address
```

Create a new user account:

```
useradd username
```

- You need to replace username with the user name that you want to create.

Run the passwd command to set a password for the new user:

```
passwd username
```

Add the new user to the sudo group:

```
usermod -aG wheel username
```

That is all. You have successfully created a sudo user on your CentOS system. You can now use this user to perform administrative tasks on your server.

Source: [How To Create a Sudo User on CentOS](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-sudo-user-on-centos/)